# What is use of <data android:scheme="oauth" android:host="t4jsample"/> in android twitter integration

Tags: android, twitter

```
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="oauth" android:host="t4jsample"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

can we use host different, and how it is related to callback url in twitter..

Comment: i want to know can we use different value in android:host="abc" then it will work or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, you want to connect to twitter.

twitter API calls login and updating status only. If you want to integrate more api calls like reading users tweet timeline, sending direct message etc., you need to include other required .jar files too.

- INTERNET Permission
- ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE Permission
- and added an Intent Filter

  ```
  <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="8"
      android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

  <application
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
      <activity
          android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
              **<data android:scheme="oauth" android:host="t4jsample"/>** //look at this here we have to be needed "oauth" for connecting to twitter..OAuth is an open standard for authorization. OAuth provides a method for clients to access server resources on behalf of a resource owner
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>
  </application>

  <!-- Permission - Internet Connect -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

  <!-- Network State Permissions -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  ```